# Achieve range-based for in older c++

Tags: c++, for-loop

I'm used to other languages that support foreach loops or the range-based for in c++11. I'm trying to emulate it in c++98.. Mainly because I don't like using the `(*it)` notation every time I need the object.

Say I have this c++11 code:

```
std::vector<int> myVec{...};
for(auto& outerLoopVar : myVec)
{
    for(auto& innerLoopVar : myVec)
    {
        // do logic
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to replicate that in c++98 than doing something like this?

```
std::vector<int> myVec;
// populate vector
for(std::vector<int>::iterator it1 = myVec.begin(); it1 < myVec.end(); it1++)
{
    int& outerLoopVar = *it1;
    for(std::vector<int>::iterator it2 = myVec.begin(); it2 < myVec.end(); it2++)
    {
        int& innerLoopVar = *it2;
        // do logic
    }
}
```

Comment: How about [Boost foreach](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/foreach.html)?

Answer (score 2):

You want to use [boost foreach](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/foreach.html):

```
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>

BOOST_FOREACH(int& elem, myVec) {
    // do logic
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not really, I mean the iterator notation is quite standard and is applicable to multiple containers and objects. Its a valuable tool which should be used. I don't really know why you don't like using the notation but I think its better if you embrace it.